# React, unable to push html element without an encolsing tag into an array

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Im composing an array of html elements in order to print them afterwards.

This is how my composition looks so far

```
for (let i = 1; i < appsData.length; i++) {
        //console.log(appsData[i][0])  //name of the permission
        //console.log(appsData[i][1]) //true false
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            appsPrint.push(<div className="row lowerlow"> </div> ) //I DONT WANT THE FINAL </div> TAG
            }
            var w = 0;
        while(w < 2){
                    appsPrint.push(<div className="col-md-6 app-div" onClick={() => this.props.history.push("'/"+appsData[i][0]+"'")}>
                        <div className="row texticon">
                            <div className="col-md-1 offset-md-1">
                                <div>
                                    <div className="appicon">
                                        <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" >
                                            <path d="M0 2v20h32v-20h-32zM30 20h-28v-16h28v16zM21 24h-10l-1 4-2 2h16l-2-2z"></path>
                                        </svg>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-2">
                                <div className="">
                                    {appsData[i][0]}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>)
        w++;
        i++;
        }
        if(i%2 != 0){
                    appsPrint.push(<div> </div>) //I DONT WANT THE INITIAL <div> TAG
        }


    }
```

But the problem is that when `if (i % 2 != 0)` happens , I want to first open a div tag, then do some stuff, and when it ends, close the  tag. Problem is, I apparently cant push this elements without its enclosing tag.

Visual studio gives an error if I do

`appsPrint.push(<div className="row lowerlow"> )`
`appsPrint.push( </div> )`

> jsx div element has no corresponding enclosing tag

So how am I supposed to do this stuff? I can convert it all in a string, and then destring it, but it would be messy.

Comment: You should not do like this. Prepare the data as needed for display. And then use map to render templete. This is not the correct way to do this

Answer (score 0):

I must say you have to make use of `...` spread syntax:

```
appsPrint = [<div className="row lowerlow">, ...appsPrint, </div> ];
```

In this case you just need to push the `<div>`s you want then spread them just as suggested.

---

But better option to have it done is with having a proper data and then just map it to render.

Like this:

```
render(){
   return ( { appsData.map((obj, i) => {
       <div className="col-md-6 app-div" onClick={() => this.props.history.push("'/"+appsData[i][0]+"'")}>
                    <div className="row texticon">
                        <div className="col-md-1 offset-md-1">
                            <div>
                                <div className="appicon">
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" >
                                        <path d="M0 2v20h32v-20h-32zM30 20h-28v-16h28v16zM21 24h-10l-1 4-2 2h16l-2-2z"></path>
                                    </svg>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-2">
                            <div className="">
                                {appsData[i][0]}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
             })}
     );
}
```